# Are there anyways to fill a structure with shorter code?

Tags: c++, c

I need to fill the attributes x and y of a structure. Given that I have a lot of members (x,y...) and everyone of them have the same attributes (read, write etc.), are there anyways I can do this in a shorter way than this ?

```
features.x.Read = GetAttribute(node,"x","Read",HexValue);
features.x.Write = GetAttribute(node,"x","Write",HexValue);
features.x.address = GetAttribute(node,"x","address",HexValue);
features.x.value = GetAttribute(node,"x","value",HexValue);

features.y.Read = GetAttribute(node,"y","Read",HexValue);
features.y.Write = GetAttribute(node,"y","Write",HexValue);
features.y.address = GetAttribute(node,"y","address",HexValue);
features.y.value = GetAttribute(node,"y","value",HexValue);
```

Thank you

Comment: you'll need to show the assembly if you want an answer to that.  What you've shown aren't "instructions".

Comment: I am sorry the word I'm looking for is not instruction. Is has nothing to do with assembly here.

Comment: Seems at the very least you could write one function that operates on both features.x and features.y, that would halve the ammount of code.

Comment: Is this supposed to be assignment or initialization?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this maybe

```
void set_members(Whatever& member, const char* name)
{
    member.Read = GetAttribute(node, name, "Read", HexValue);
    member.Write = GetAttribute(node, name, "Write", HexValue);
    member.address = GetAttribute(node, name, "address", HexValue);
    member.value = GetAttribute(node, name, "value", HexValue);
}

set_members(feature.x, "x");
set_members(feature.y, "y");
```

I don't know what `Whatever` should be, but you can figure that out. Maybe even make it a templated type.

Answer (score 6):

Well, while not fewer instructions, at least fewer keystrokes and somewhat easier to read:

```
#define FILL(a, b) features.a.b = GetAttribute(node,#a,#b,HexValue)

FILL(x, Read);
FILL(x, Write);
FILL(x, address);
FILL(x, value);

FILL(y, Read);
FILL(y, Write);
FILL(y, address);
FILL(y, value);

#undef FILL
```

Comment: ...at the expense of easy debugging, but +1 since OP asks for 'shorter way'

Comment: @Bathsheba Agreed, however there is nearly always a cost associated with anything.

Comment: There's no such thing as a free lunch. Now if you excuse me, I have a free lunch to steal.

Comment: @Bathsheba How does this make it harder to debug ?

Answer (score 3):

Both C and C++ have aggregate initialization: showing the C-style: http://ideone.com/EXKtCo

```
struct X
{
   int some;
   const char* really_long;
   double and_annoying_variable_names;
};

int main()
{
    struct X x = { 42, "hello world", 3.14 };
    // reassign:
    struct X y = { 0, "dummy", 0.0 };
    x = y;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @alk Oh, aha. Sorry for the non-C-isms (I do C++ mainly). Hope this fixed your concerns. I'd appreciate if next time you just called me out ("Could you fix the sample" instead of "Please elaborate"). Cheers

Comment: Actually i don't recommend this way to init the aggregate data structure. If there is a lot of same type (for example, int) data member, and you change the data member sequence order in the structure later, you will get runtime error instead of compile error.

Comment: @ZijingWu Actually, that's a rather strange assumption. You'd get semantically incorrect code. You'd **hope** you get some kind of symptom.

Comment: That's not strange assumption. That's an common case you have multiple int in your structure, let's say RECT, you have four int in it. And SIZE you have two.

Comment: @ZijingWu The assumption was that you "will get [_sic_] runtime error". This is simply not true. You _might_. (By the way, I made this clear, by explaining what you _would_ know, instead of the assumption)

Comment: Agreed, I should say "switch two same type data member position"